# ProLiant DL360 G7 won't boot, Health LED blinking RED, SID has both CPUs in Amber

Tags: hp-proliant

I have an HP Proliant DL360 G7 that I had working earlier today. It has 2 Xeon 2.4 CPUs and 16GB memory. I had it working fine earlier today as I was installing VMware on system to get it ready for a project. I shut down the system correctly and disconnected the system to take to the project location. When i get to the location and start connecting the server to the site's network I get a RED blinking Health LED when i power it up. I check in the SID and it shows now that the 2 CPUs in the SID has solid AMBER lights. This wasn't there before. If i get near the server I can see it is semi-on since i do here the fans in low speed and the power button light is green. I doubt it has anything to do with the CPUs. Not sure if moving it out and having it put sideways instead of laying it down can cause an issue which i doubt. Any suggestions as to what it could be?

Answer (score 1):

Reseat the CPUs and RAM.

If that doesn't work, start with a minimal config: 1 CPU, 1 DIMM, boot... and add components until the system boots consistently.

Comment: I just tried reseating the CPUs and RAM as well as the minimal config and even if i just put one CPU and one DIMM i still get an amber light on the CPU in the SID. I also changed the 2032 battery just in case that could also be the issue and nothing. You hear it want to turn on, but you see the drive light blink once and then they turn off and you hear the fans running at very low speed. Not sure what could of caused this issue. I highly doubt the rack mount server being laid down face down or standing sideways would cause this issue.